# XPath getting attributes of divs

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to learn xpath by writing a simple program that will list the fixtures of Premier League in footbal from the following page:
http://www.livefootball.com/football/england/premier-league/

I've already collected all the dates using the `//dl[@class='mElHeaderDet']` statement and all the general match details using `//div[@class='mEl show']/dl/*`. The problem is however, it seems that every match in that page has it's own unique ID, for example the first match goes like this:

```
<dl id="fid1-1228229" class="even">
  <dd class="mElStatus">16:00</dd>
  <dd class="mElO1">Arsenal</dd>
  <dd class="mElScore">v</dd>
  <dd class="mElO2">Sunderland</dd>
</dl>
```

in this example the fid1-1228229 is what interests me. How would I approach getting a list of all the matches' IDs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve list of all ids you can use

```
//div[@class='mEl show']/dl[not(contains(@class,'mElHeaderDet'))]/@id
```

Above Xpath will return you list of values of `id` attribute for divs whose class is not `mElHeaderDet`.

**OR**

Alternatively you can use this xpath as well

```
//div[@class='mEl show']/dl[starts-with(@id,'fid')]/@id
```

Above XPath will return you list of ids of all the divs whose ID attribute value starts with `fid`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any idea how I should format it to use in c#? I'm using the HTML Agility Pack and instead of the list of IDs I'm getting a matches' details formatted like this: `20:30
Borussia Dortmund
v
Werder Bremen` Here's the code: `var ids = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='mEl show']/dl[starts-with(@id,'fid')]/@id");`

Comment: I am not familiar with C# & HTML Agility Pack. A quick google search directed me to [THIS](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) example. This should get you going.